# CKEditor: How to insert anchor tag into document?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

On the surface this should be easy:

```
CKEDITOR.instances[Object.keys(CKEDITOR.instances)[0]].insertHtml( html );
```

...where html is a string of an actual HTML tag.  Sadly, however, this doesn't work.  When I click the button on my page that calls this code, nothing happens.  It doesn't appear anywhere in the document at all, not even in Source mode.

I tried using insertElement:

```
var element = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml( html );
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.insertElement( element );
```

...and all it did was stick a little red flag in the document that was nothing; if I saved the document and reloaded it, it was gone.

The goal is to insert:

```
<a name="something"></a>
```

But the only thing that works is insertText() and that turns it into "safe" text, i.e. the < and > turn into lt; and gt;.

Help please? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you used the code from the CKEDITOR Documentation (https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-insertElement)

1. You probably ran into an issue, which says, that empty anchors show
       a little red flag in the editor
       (https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/14689). Unfortunately there seems to
       be no way of CKEDITOR from doing this.
2. Empty Links are removed from
       CKEDITOR automatically. You can add data-cke-survive="true" so these
       links aren't removed, <a href="#" data-cke-survive="true"></a>

Regards

Comment: Thanks!  Yep that was it. It's not a 100% solution for ME but in the case of the question here it is.  I put that data-cke in there and it kept it when I went to Source mode, but when I went out of it and back in, it was gone.  I think I'm gonna have to require the user to select some text so it'll stick.  Thanks again!

Comment: Correction... once I removed the href="#" it behaved fine. Not sure why I put href="#" with a name="something" too.  Silly me.  Again, thanks for your help!!